# Should I disable form input while processing the form?

Tags: forms

I found some similar questions, but not related to the form while it's processing. Basically what I want to know is whether or not it's necessary to disable form inputs while it's sending it to the server on a web/mobile application.

For example, the user is creating his account and fill the form with his name, e-mail, etc. and then press the button "submit".

At this point, should I disable the inputs to prevent user to edit this information?

I don't know if it's worth the effort to do this, or if it will even have a positive impact on the UX. Currently what I do is to disable just the submit button. It changes it's state to have a loader, indicating it's processing and the click functionality is disabled as well, but only on the submit button.

How should I handle this situation while the form is processing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Forms should not be editable after it has been submitted, but only if you expect the form will be used only once per user (ie creating an account).**

***One time form***

Having a loader and a disabled submit button are good indicators, but I think it would be better to hide the entire form. For example, if someone is creating an account and clicks 'submit', the UI shows a progress indicator and after that a confirmation message. After that the user can continue in the flow (ie continue to login and use your product after registration).

[image]

***Forms with more than one use***

However, what if someone is editing content via a form? In this case the above is not a correct way to do it. In that case I would not use the label 'submit', but use 'save' or 'publish' instead. Users will only be able to save/publish again after processing has been finished. Disabling the form input is not necessary. Think about when you work in a text editor and save during editing. You can continue while the 'form' (your text) is being processed.