# Giving user a visual cue that form controls are disabled after clicking submit, while the form is being processed?

Tags: forms, visual-cues, disabled

[image]

Never tested or researched this, tbh.

After clicking submit, the submit button's label is replaced by a "processing" animation indicator. Functionally - the form is disabled, so user can't mess up.

Is there a value in giving the user a visual cue that form is disabled, changing the state of inputs and form controls into disabled state?

Hm, not really sure. Maybe first time, as a reassurance they can't mess up incidentally. But does user need that kind of reassurance? Would they say, ok this is now disabled so I am at ease clicking around and messing about? I am not assuming so. Also, I assume after first time, on every subsequent time using the form dialog, visually changing the dialog after click becomes...eye-straining. It is useless clue, a known information, but your eye still registers the change on controls and dialog, and therefore it robs you of a little bit of attention, even though you might not think of it.

These are my assumptions - let me know your thought and experience, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [Should I disable form input while processing the form?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/108520/should-i-disable-form-input-while-processing-the-form).

I would hide the entire form, and redirect the user to the next screen.